# Down for the Countif

Tags: discussion

[Countif](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/countif) has 49 questions total. Of those, 47 also have an excel tag. [One](https://superuser.com/questions/796084/libreoffice-calc-countifs-with-date) has a libre office tag. And [one](https://superuser.com/questions/924640/count-two-different-text-items-in-a-row-or-column) only has it (countif).

There's no description or summary of the tag and it's not very useful. I don't know if "countif" exists in other scenarios with other programs, but right now it's a useless tag.

#### My Suggestion-

All `countif` tags should be replaced with `worksheet-function` if not already tagged with that. And then **burninate** Countif

Also, I couldn't think of a more clever title - I welcome an improvement.

Comment: Countdown for count If ?

Comment: @Hennes I feel like puzzling.stackexchange is missing you.

Comment: I agree that it is worthy of burnination.  I can see @random's point only from the perspective of it not being worth the priority or effort, or bumping a bunch of questions only for that reason (i.e., "it ain't worth the gunpowder to blow it up").

Answer (score 4):

Eh.

This one seems OK as a tag on its own and doesn't need to be subsumed into a greater tag. It's not like a "cell" tag.

A question about the `=COUNTIF` function isn't too widely general and the tag isn't too inside itself as if it was something like a version tag would be.

Comment: Fair enough. [vlookup](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vlookup) exists.

Comment: countif (and vlookup for that matter), may meet the definition of an OK tag, but what value do they serve?  Nobody is following tags that are that granular (do we have countif-only experts?), and only a small fraction of related questions have the tag.  So it doesn't help the question get answered or help users reliably find questions.

Comment: Still, searching for countif helps finding at laest the questions that do have the tag.